# What is the proper way to handle MPI communicators in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, mpi, openmpi

I read that is recommended to use the MPI module rather than include mpif.h file. However, I get the following error

> Error: There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘mpi_comm_split’

when I run this program

```
program hello_world
  use mpi_f08
  implicit none
  ! include 'mpif.h'
  integer :: ierr, num_procs, my_id,newcomm
  integer :: color,key

  call MPI_INIT ( ierr )
  color =1; key=0
  call MPI_COMM_RANK (MPI_COMM_WORLD, my_id, ierr)
  call MPI_COMM_SIZE (MPI_COMM_WORLD, num_procs, ierr)

  call MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, color,key,newcomm, ierr)

  call MPI_FINALIZE ( ierr )

end
```

The error disappears if I include 'mpif.h' instead of using the MPI module. Why is that?

Comment: Never tried it, but it looks like the type to use for f08 interface uses `type(MPI_comm)` for `newcomm`...

Comment: Related to what Gilles has said what happens if you simple "use mpi"? What compiler and version and what mpi and version might be useful as well.

Comment: *The error disappears if I include 'mpif.h' instead of using the MPI module. Why is that?*  Because, by using the mpi module you are enabling the compiler to check that routine formal and actual arguments match at compile time.  The `include` approach lets all sorts of nonsense happen at run time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `use mpi_f08` interface introduces different wrapper types for the different MPI handle objects. While in `mpif.h` and the `use mpi` interfaces all handles are simply `INTEGER`s, in the `use mpi_f08` interface there are `TYPE(MPI_Comm)`, `TYPE(MPI_File)`, etc. This allows the compiler to perform checks for things like passing a communicator handle where a file handle is expected.

This is a breaking change on the source level as code must be rewritten, e.g.,

```
INTEGER :: newcomm
```

becomes

```
TYPE(MPI_Comm) :: newcomm
```

On the binary level there is no change since all those `MPI_Xyz` types are simply an `INTEGER` wrapped in a `TYPE` specifier, which makes them layout compatible. Old Fortran code can still exchange MPI handles with modern Fortran code and vice versa - the `INTEGER` handle value can be set or extracted via `newcomm%MPI_VAL`.

Comment: Thank you! I am getting another error when using MPI_types in reduce function such as `call MPI_Allreduce( x,y , N, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, newcomm, ierr )` that Symbol ‘mpi_double’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type. How should this be modified? using `type(MPI_DOUBLE)` doesn't help.

Comment: `MPI_DOUBLE` corresponds to the C/C++ `double` type. It must not be used in Fortran code. Use `MPI_REAL` or whatever the type of `x` and `y` is (`MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION`, etc.)

Comment: However if I have a real(c_double) I would hope a corresponding MPI type is available...

Comment: Isn't `real(c_double)` only meant to be used when interfacing to C/C++ code?

Comment: Not really@HristoIliev but it is one way to get the number of bytes consistent, so for interfacing with c it is nice. On Intel then (KIND=8) works, but if and when one wants to use gfortran then it can be easier to replace that with c_double which is more portable by design. Whether there are other implications I am not sure, but it works in pure fortran find-n-dandy.